# A button with light indicator and shine in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I am trying to create the following design in WPF:

A sidebar menu with the buttons. A button consists of several elements (an icon, text) and a light indicator.

Unfortunately, it only partially worked for me. What I have managed so far:
A button with the icon and text. There is a light indicator, unfortunately it is not the part of the rounded rectangle, but a rounded rectangle next to it.

What I haven't managed at all is this glow to the right of light indicator.

Two questions i ask myself are the following:

- how can I make light indicator a part of the rounded rectangle
- how to create such light shine.

[image][image]

This is my reference:

[image]

My code to generate a button:

```
<Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--  Selected  -->
                        <Border
                            x:Name="btnSelected"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Width="225"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            CornerRadius="10" />
                        <!--  Indicator  -->
                        <Rectangle
                            Name="Indicator"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Width="6"
                            Height="42"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource SecundaryBlueColor}"
                            RadiusX="0"
                            RadiusY="0">
                            <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect
                                    Direction="0"
                                    ShadowDepth="3"
                                    Softness="0.6"
                                    Color="#5B8DEF" />
                            </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <!--  Icon  -->
                        <Path
                            x:Name="Icon"
                            Width="24"
                            Height="24"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Data="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}"
                            Stretch="None" />

                        <!--  Text  -->
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="txtName"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="12,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />


                    </Grid>
```

Update:
this way I solved a problem with rounded rectangle (rectangle replaced by border with cornerRadius. Now it looks like this:
[image]
The Problem with glow / shine is still unsolved.

New Code:

```
 <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--  Selected  -->
                        <Border
                            x:Name="btnSelected"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Width="225"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            CornerRadius="10" />
                        <!--  Indicator  -->
                        <Border Name="Indicator" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0,5,5,0">
                        </Border>
                        <!--  Icon  -->
                        <Path
                            x:Name="Icon"
                            Width="24"
                            Height="24"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Data="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}"
                            Stretch="None" />

                        <!--  Text  -->
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="txtName"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="12,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />


                    </Grid>
```

Comment: Use a dropshadow.

Comment: If I use dropshadow I habe a glow only inside the button, but not an overlay of the area around a Button light indicator.